# `\` symbol in mathematics - meaning

Tags: divisibility, inverse

I saw this equation `UNEXP = RS \ PM` and am a bit confused about the `\` symbol, is that same as `/` division?

I am reading an article on evaluating a recommender system and it says that

> Let PM be a set of recommendations generated by a primitive prediction model and RS denote the recommendations generated by a recommender system

Comment: No, it is the set complement symbol. That is, $RS\backslash PM$ is the set of all languages that belongs to $RS$, but not to $PM$.

Comment: You will need to include more context.  Where did you see the equation, and what topic was being discussed?  For instance: in some computer languages, $\backslash$ indicates *rounded division*.  In set theory, $\setminus$ is the set difference operator.  And so on.

Comment: @GrahamKemp This is in the context of complexity classes of languages. I have seen the notations before, especially UNEXP.

Comment: @GrahamKemp  check my update

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг you are right

Comment: @charlesokojie You are welcome

Comment: @charlesokojie Then астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг  is right.